# Any way to get rid of Tk window while using Snack?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use `Snack` to make a simple mp3 player. It works together with `Tkinter`. Here is what documentation says about its usage:

```
The beginning of a program that uses Snack might look like:

    from Tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

    import tkSnack
    tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)

    # Now you can use tkSnack commands and objects
    # ...
```

The `root = Tk()` line opens an empty window, which could be closed after the initialization of Snack and Snack will continue to work the same (paying, pausing, resuming, loading audios and so on).

Is there any way to avoid the opening of this window? May you explain why such a library needs a graphical window in order to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `root = Tk().withdraw()` then the Tk window will be created but not displayed. Hopefully it will not even flash on screen.

The Tcl snack package is a Tk extension and has a number of commands that call Tk functions. So the original design just didn't break it into windowing and non-windowing sections. However Tk is not required to use snack, but you must run an event loop at some point. For instance in a Tcl script (no Tk) you can do:

```
package require snack
snack::sound snd -file $filename
snd play -blocking 0
after 5000 {set waiting 1}
vwait waiting
```

This will setup a `snd` command with the file data configured and then tell it to play. However, nothing will happen until we start the event loop (`vwait waiting`) and in this case we schedule something to happen in 5 seconds to time the wait out.

Looking at the tkSnack sources can probably help you translate the above into something pythonic. They are just a wrapper around the Tcl/Tk package. But I suspect running the Tk window will help in getting the music playing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `root.withdraw()` method to hide your window.

Optionally, if you are ever planing to use it again, use `root.deiconify()`